# Making a window for a bash script password through Python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am writing a script that is comprised of a graphical user interface. This GUI has a button the user clicks, which executes a bash script hosted on DropBox. I then write the output of the bash script to a log file.

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Desktop/'
cmd = 'curl -fsSL https://www.dropbox.com/BASH_SCRIPT_dl=1 | bash'
with open(path+'Step 1 Log.txt', 'w') as out:
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=out, stderr=out)
print('Step 1 completed. Continue onto Step 2.\n\n')
```

The issue I am having is that this bash script contains sudo commands (to handle permissions to install new software). When the bash script reaches the sudo commands, there is no terminal window in which to enter the password. Currently, the resulting log file shows results for all the bash commands prior to the sudo commands. I am assuming the bash script simply terminates.

A possible workaround I thought of was to have the user type in their password at the beginning of my script, save it as a variable, and then pass it in at the Popen command. However, all my efforts looking into the Popen.communicate() method confused me. I've also looked into the pexpect library, but I would prefer to use a stdlib solution.

I would anyway much prefer the user to simply enter their password when prompted by the bash script. I am running Python 3.4 but will port the entire project back to 2.7 once complete (the native python version on MacBooks).

EDIT:
Thanks to `Etan Reisner` for the suggestion. My knowledge of bash scripting is limited, this was made from a coworker of mine. The function containing the sudo command is as follows:

```
function setsudo() {
    echo -e "\nPlease enter your laptop password: "
    sudo -v
    if [[ ${?} -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "!! User Password not accepted, exiting....!!"
        exit 1; 
    fi
    while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &
}
```

I am looking through the sudo manual and playing around in Terminal to understand what should replace `sudo -v`.  How exactly is `-A` to be implemented?

Comment: don't use sudo in a script, just check that you are root with `os.getuid() == 0` and error out if you are not

Comment: @user2085282 Suggesting that an entire script running as root is better than only running commands that need root as root is not a particularly good suggestion.

Comment: Most of your code is bizarre in many ways. Why not just look up the user's home directory, or just `os.path.expanduser('~')`? Why call `str` when it will either do nothing (if it's already a string) or cause confusing grief (if it's somehow, e.g., a `bytes`, so you end up with `/Users/b'me'/Desktop` as your path)? Why write a command line piping `curl` to `bash` instead of just using subprocess pipes (and, maybe `urllib` or `requests`)? Why put the `open` ahead of the `with` statement—and, worse, why call `close` on something after it? All of this stuff makes it much harder to debug your code.

Comment: I was not aware of the `os.path.expanduser` method, thanks for pointing that out. Before my script, the `cmd` variable was entered in Terminal manually; I sought to automate it through a GUI, so this was the most straightforward process that came to me at the time. As for `.close()`, I will remedy my code to eliminate it, thanks for the edits.

Comment: The intent of `setsudo()` is to ask for the password exactly once no matter how long the script that calls it takes. See [Temporarlly increasing sudo's timeout for the duration of an install script](http://serverfault.com/q/266039/3933) and especially [this](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/3118588).

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `sudo` `-A` argument is for:

> -A
>
> Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's
>   terminal. If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly
>   graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's password and
>   output the password to the standard output. If the SUDO_ASKPASS
>   environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper
>   program. .... If no askpass program is available, sudo will exit
>   with an error.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this and update. Do you have the link to the documentation? EDIT: Nevermind, I found it.

Comment: @user3239106: A few things to note: (1) If you only care about your own platform, the answer to that question is generally `man sudo`. (2) If you care about cross-platform, usually you want to search `site:pubs.opengroup.org sudo`, because that will quickly find you the POSIX standard docs… but in this case, [`sudo` is not actually part of the standard, it's just something that every BSD and GNU system, and most other *nix-like systems, all happen to offer (sometimes built-in, sometimes as an add-on)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48522/how-universal-is-sudo).

Comment: There might be an issue with `sudo -A`: it may clear the sudo timeout causing `SUDO_ASKPASS` program to be launched for each `sudo` call in your script. See [Graphically ask for password in a bash script and retain default sudo timeout setting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81181/1321).